# Why this closure call doesn't end up in a recursive call?

Tags: recursion, groovy, closures

I'm new to Groovy and I'm studying closures in the oficial docs. [The 'delegate of a closure' topic](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegate_of_a_closure) gives the example bellow:

[image]

So, in the number 5, I know that delegate is set default to owner, that in the case is the enclosing closure `enclosed`.

So, why calling

```
{ -> delegate }.call()
```

inside the `enclosed` closure doesn't end up in a recursive call? Looks like a recursion to me, but if you run the code, isn't a recursion. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def enclosed = {
    // delegate == owner == enclosed (variable)
    { ->
        // When this closure is called return the delegate (enclosed) 
        delegate 
    }.call() // Called immediately                          

    // above closure is same as writing
    // return delegate
}

// When enclosed in called the delegate is returned immediately
// from the invocation of the inner closure, hence the result of the 
// closure call is the closure (delegate) itself
assert enclosed() == enclosed
```

Keep in mind that whatever is suppose to happen inside `enclosed` closure will not happen until `enclosed()` is called. :) Does it depict a clear picture now?

Comment: Could you put in your answer the observation that @Emmanuel Rosa did in his answer that to a recursive call occurs we need `{ -> delegate }.call().call()`? I think this is very important to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I would agree but I felt that was not relevant to question that was asked in the first place. Question was "What am I missing?". Answer was the understanding of how closure works. No doubt that .call().call() will result in recursion but the whole code block will be meaningless. Moreover, how do you make sure (apart from looking at the code) that .call() returns a `Closure` based on which you can invoke .call() again. It would be better if you check first .call() `instanceof` Closure then make .call(). I am glad if I have helped you on this.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `{ -> delegate }.call()` in the `enclosed` closure doesn't cause a recursive call because `call()` is invoked on a different closure; the one created in `enclosed`. To get a recursive call you can do this: `{ -> delegate }.call().call()`. The first `call()` returns `enclosed`, and the second invokes it.